# Why rails is generating empty models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to generate some models but they are being generated without attributes.

I'm using a linux system and the rails version is:
rails --version
Rails 4.0.0

I've tried to generate the models using this commands:

```
rails g scaffold Bsdsd description:string test:string oaso:integer
```

and

```
rails g model Asdsd description:string test:string oaso:integer
```

The first results in this empty class model everything else ok:

```
class Bsdsd < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

The second results in test files, migrations file(that contains the attributes) and this class model:

```
class Asdsd < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

How can I correct this behavior?

Comment: What do you expect generated models to contain?

Comment: class Adress < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :desc
end

Comment: No, Rails will not do that for you. You have to define the accessibility yourself, or else, by default, all your fields would be attr_accessible by default.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Model attributes are inferred from database columns, so you don't need them specified in model classes.

In Rails 3.2 you had (if I remember correctly)

```
# attr_accessible :description, :test, :oaso
```

line generated. But protected attributes are deprecated in Rails 4.0 and replaced by strong parameters mechanism.

Comment: It's because of the 4.0 rails version? I'm learning rails right now but if not wrong in the 3.2 version it was creating the attributes or not? thank you

Answer (score 2):

Nothing you're doing is wrong. But you're checking the wrong files. Look for CreateAsdsdsMigration (in the **migrations** directory) file and you'll see the auto-generated fields there

Comment: So I should not expect any attributes in the model classes? It just reflects the database fields? thank you

Answer (score 0):

For those coming from Grails or Django, note that Rails creates the database FIRST-- not the other way around, where domainclass.groovy or models.py creates the database tables for you AFTER you define them. Look for yourapp/db/schema.rb and inside are all your classes and their field definitions.