# My Ruby Class turns out to be empty, why cant i create attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class

I am new at ruby on rails. I create a class named member with some variables such as name, surname ext. When I open member.rb under app/models, the class seems empty:

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I realised it when I run `member.all`. It gives error:

```
NameError : undefined local variable or method 'member' for main:Object
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why rails is generating empty models?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323870/why-rails-is-generating-empty-models)

Comment: Did you generate the model using `rails generate...`? You probably mean your column names, which are in your migration file. What version of Rails? Also `member.all` is wrong, it would be `Member.all`.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, first. If you made it with `rails generate ...` then your class has the attributes. This was weird to me coming from C++ and having all of the attributes stated at the top. This is different in Ruby.

However, if you made it like a regular C++ programmer would think of making it, it wouldn't have any variables Like just creating the Model.rb file, it wouldn't work in the sense you're trying to get it to work.

Second, when you're trying to search for your class's objects. You have to do `Member.all`. Capitalzation is very important in this.

When you search you can do `Member.find(:id)` with the id of the object you're looking for.

Lastly, to start changing the attributes of a class object, you'll have to start using this in your class: `attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name`, etc.

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The class seems empty, but it is not.  Rails inspects your database schema to find what columns are defined in that table.  It then dynamically creates the accessors for those columns.  This is all done for you by active record.  All you have to do is have a class name which is derived from the table name (e.g., a table named "members" and a class named "Member", and have that class derive from ActiveRecord::Base.

Ruby makes this possible because class definitions are open for modification at run-time.  Any class or object may have methods added or removed.  Rails makes heavy use of this "metaprogramming" capability.

Your undefined variable error is happening because "member" (lowercase) refers to a variable.  To refer to the class, be sure to capitalize it: "Member".